# Circular argument in proof?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, alternative-proof

[image]

See the part (B). In it, the author "proves" the limit $\lim\limits_{|x|\to\infty}\left(1+\frac 1x\right)^x$. The part concerning $x\to -\infty$ is in the next page but in that, he just takes $y=-x$ and $y\to\infty$ and establishes the limit using the first case, so I didn't include that part in the image.

I have two concerns (questions) regarding this :

(a) Isn't $e$ *defined* that way? How does one *prove* a definition ? I can understand proof of a definition if we assume some other definition and show that it's equivalent to this one but I don't see the author doing that.

(b) The author states that "See that when $n\to\infty$ ($n$ going through positive integers only), we have $(1+1/n)^n\to e$ and $(1+1/(n+1))^{n+1}\to e$" and then he concludes his first part of the "proof" using squeeze theorem. Isn't this a circular argument ? How do we know beforehand that those expressions tend to $e$ ?

---

Bottom line, do you guys think this is a proof ? I don't think so but I'd like to hear opinions of other MSE users.

Also, I'd like if someone posts a different proof of the same using some other standard definition of $e$, I suppose (probably the infinite series definition would work). Thanks.

Comment: You don't prove a definition. The limit of so and so is shown to converge to some irrational number we have chosen to call $e$.

Comment: I think he is just proving that the limit exists and he names it $e$.

Comment: @AlvinLepik, see my concern (a). I agree with you and I stated just that in my question. Although, is there a proof of this using an alternate defintion of $e$ (preferably the infinite series definiton) ?

Comment: As I read it, I believe that the definition $$e=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$ only applies to $n\in \Bbb N$ (i.e. $e$ is the limit of a _sequence_), and this is a proof to show that it holds even when you allow $n\in \Bbb R$ (i.e. as a limit to a real function).

Comment: There are many ways to define $e$.  Each author will choose one way, then the other definitions become proofs because you have to prove they are all equivalent.  How exactly did your book do it when $e$ was first introduced?

Comment: @Arthur, that might just be the case. I can't find the exact way the author defined it (the book is quite big to browse through) but I'll take your word for it. +1

Comment: Just out of curiosity, was there a calculation of $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}$ on the previous page of the book?

Comment: @Arthur, yup, there is. It's the (A) part of the section, the second (B) part being the one in the pic.

Comment: You have to at least tell us what the definition of $e$ is in that book.

Comment: @CarstenS, I didn't find one in the current chapter. Maybe it's given in a chapter that's not in my semester syllabus. ._.

Comment: @learner Responding your question on the comment, Rudin defines $e$ as the series and proves $e$ equals the limit of this question.

Answer (score 3):

The proof is about the limit for real $x$. It relies on a definition of $e$ stated for integer $n$. There is no circular argument and the author is not defining $e$ twice. He is showing that the limit by reals is the same as that by integers.

Technically speaking, the squeeze theorem is invoked after showing that $\lfloor x\rfloor<x<\lfloor x\rfloor+1$ is preserved by monotonocity of the function $\left(1+\dfrac1x\right)^x$.

Comment: The author doesn't explicitly point it out that he's defining those two limits as $e$.

Comment: @learner: chances are pretty high that this is stated earlier in the book.

Comment: In my own edition of a similar book, this exercise just follows another which is about the limit by integers, which is established by means of the binomial theorem on $(1+1/n)^n$.

Answer (score 0):

One can define sequence $$a_n = \left(1+\frac 1 n\right)^n$$ *(which is just a function $a\colon\mathbb N\to \mathbb R$)*

and one can define function of positive real variable $f\colon\mathbb R_{>0}\to\mathbb R$ $$f(x) = \left(1+\frac 1 x\right)^x$$

Since $(a_n)$ is bounded monotone sequence, it is convergent, and we denote it's limit by $e$ (one possible definition of $e$). But, author is not establishing a limit of a sequence, but a limit of function, and uses convergence of sequence $(a_n)$ and Sandwich theorem to prove that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n = \lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)$$

Comment: "Since $(a_n)$ is bounded monotone sequence,..."
$$~$$ 
How should I show this? I think monotonicity can be shown using derivatives or something but how do you show that it's bounded?

Comment: @learner, see, for example, [this](http://planetmath.org/ConvergenceOfTheSequence11nn).